# Why do we need a UserHandle in many API declarations

Tags: android, android-source

In Android Open Source Project, a lot of core API declarations have an integer parameter userId in the end. I traced back and figured out the integer comes from a class called "UserHandle.java". There is a simple comments saying this class represents a user on the device. It still confuses me. Why do we need such a class? What's the difference between different values of the class, such as "USER_OWNER", "USER_CURRENT", "USER_CURRENT_OR_SELF"?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

Ever since Jelly Bean, Android platform has supported multiple users. This means that multiple users may be able to use one device, yet not be able to access other user's files or communicate with another user's app.
The first user on the device is user 0. The rest start their numbering from 10,11,... (In JB the numbering was 1,2...).
`USER_OWNER` is user 0.
He has some extra privileges over the other users (mostly access certain settings that others can't or uninstall an app for all users).
Multiple users on one device requires that only one user can be active in a specific point in time, this user is referred to as `USER_CURRENT` (since Kitkat().
In general one user's application can't send a broadcast message or an `Intent` to other user's apps. 
Only apps with system permissions can do that (for example when the battery is running low, an intent will be sent to all).
Whenever you send an `Intent` from your app, the system service verifies whether this is a valid Intent i.e. if its supposed to reach all users then it's not.

This means that even if you were to use a certain api with the wrong userId (for example you force userId=0 even though this is user 10), then your call will receive a `SecurityException`.

To avoid such exceptions, there is also the option to send an `Intent` with `USER_CURRENT_OR_SELF`.
This means you're trying to send to the current user, but if he's not allowed to receive the Intent, let the same user who sent the Intent receive it.